# Change the value of a cell having particular pattern in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have one Excel sheet in which there is only one column consisting of numerical values. But there are some cells where the data is misprinted because it is logged data from logger. I want to remove the term '-2' and multiply the remaining value by 10^-2.

Data screenshot:

[image: Image showing sample data]

Code screenshot:

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: You tagged this as `pandas` but you only reference Excel.  Did you read this in as a pandas dataframe from Excel?

Comment: please add code how are you reading  excel. Also try to add some mock test data to indicate the data structure(pandas/dictionary/list) used you

Comment: Is it only -2, or can you also have -3, -4 etc?

Comment: I have -3 -4 also.

Comment: Yes I read this file in pandas as df. I am not getting exactly how to sort this because dtype is object and I have '-' sign at first place also in some cells.

Comment: please print your pandas dataframe to show the values inside of it... I will help you if I can see what your Pandas is

Comment: I have printed the pandas dataframe but I am not able to guess any operation to get desired result.

Comment: I have added screenshot of code. I am beginner in this. I don't have enough idea how I should ask for answer.

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code. [Edit] your question to include code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images are problematic for [many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), including that they don't allow copy-pasting text for testing or searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

I made a simple test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'z': [1.525, -1.234, -2.345, '1.32-2', '-2.54-5']})
```

This tries to convert things to nueric values, but will put a "NaN" in the places it fails.

```
df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['z'], errors='coerce')
```

Then I make a column where everything is a string, and overwrite the entries that were "NaN" when trying to convert the first time. The overwriting uses a regular expression to make the failed scientific notation "-" into the string "e-""

```
df['c'] = df['z'].astype(str)
df.loc[df['b'].isna(), 'c'] = df['z'].str.replace(r'(\d+)(-)(\d+)', r'\1e-\3', regex=True)
```

Now that the string format is correct, this can convert them.

```
df['d'] = pd.to_numeric(df['c'])
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
print(df)
         a      b         c         d
0    1.525  1.525     1.525  1.525000
1   -1.234 -1.234    -1.234 -1.234000
2   -2.345 -2.345    -2.345 -2.345000
3   1.32-2    NaN   1.32e-2  0.013200
4  -2.54-5    NaN  -2.54e-5 -0.000025
```

Then just grab the column you want:

```
df_new = df[['d']].copy().rename(columns={'d':'z'})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. This worked for me. Also as a beginner I am not able to get following command of code, can you explain it to me?    str.replace(r'(\d+)(-)(\d+)', r'\1e-\3', regex=True)

Comment: You're welcome! In this regex, we have three "capture groups", in `( )`. It finds digits (`\d`) that occur 1 or more times in a row `+` and stores those in Group 1. Then it looks for a `-` char, and stores it in Group 2. Finally, it finds another sequence of digits (your exponent) and stores it in Group 3. If it found the above pattern, it replaces it with the numbers from Grp 1 `\1`, then the string `e-`, and finally Grp 3 `\3`. The leading minus sign, if there, just carries over. Search for regex cheat sheets for more. Please mark the answer as accepted, and this comment as helpful if it is.

Comment: No problem. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. Thanks, and take care.

Answer (score 0):

The `object` data type will allow you to use the vectorized string methods. You could try the `str.extract` method and a regex to extract the characters you want.

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1.452659',
                         '1.480596',
                         '8.2688-2',
                         '-0.13738',
                         '2.9929-4',
                         '0.4102637']})

df['a'] = df['a'] \
    .str.extract(r'([\d+\.+]+)-?\d?') \
    .astype(float)
```

This will return the data frame with column `a` as floats.

```
          a
0  1.452659
1  1.480596
2  8.268800
3  0.137380
4  2.992900
5  0.410264
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` accessor like below, and I also create a sample dataframe as an example:

```
# Just a sample DataFrame like your dataset.
df = pd.DataFrame(["1.452649", "-0.0254878", "8.2145-2", "-0.245785", "5.125457-2"],
 columns=["col"])

#First you need to change your column data type to string(object).
df["col"] = df["col"].astype("object")

#Now you can use str to edit and work with object data type.
# I first changed those problematic values to numeric (I also multiplied them with 1e-2 as you want them)
df.loc[df["col"].str.endswith('-2'), "col"] = (df.loc[df["col"].str.endswith('-2'), "col"].str.split('-').str[0].astype(np.float64)*(1e-2))

# Now we change whole column to numeric type
df["col"] = df["col"].astype(np.float64)
```